# Remove header w/o losing resizeability

Tags: handsontable

Here below the table i'm currently working on it. What I'm trying to achieve is to remove the header (A, B, C, ...) without losing the resizeability feature for the columns.

```
'config' : [
    'columns': {
        ['data':6, 'type': 'numeric', 'readOnly': false],
        ['data':7, 'type': 'numeric', 'readOnly': false],
    },
    'copyPaste' : true,
    'colHeaders' : false,
    'fillHandle': false,
    'manualColumnResize': true,
    'colHeaders': true,
    'wordWrap' : false,
]
```

Basically, once I set `manualColumnResize = True` the A,B,C Header appers. Is there a way to keep the manual resize without the header?

Answer (score 0):

You have the `colHeaders` option listed twice. Remove the one that is set to true and it should remove the headers.

**EDIT:** I believe the resize functionality actually requires the headers. When you hover in between two columns' headers,  you trigger the selector to expand or retract the size of the column. If you want to remove the (A, B, C) default header names, you can always pass a [custom function](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.4.1/Options.html#colHeaders) to overwrite them:

```
...
// as function
colHeaders: function(index) {
  return index + ': AB';
}
...
```